# How to clear textbox value after insert to the database in c#?

Tags: c#, events, textbox, textchanged

In my program have 3 textboxes. which are for subtotal,discount and grand total.Subtotal value will display after some calculations and user should type discount manually.Then after type discount value in textbox it will display grandtotal value automatically in grandtotal textbox.For this I used textchange event like this

```
private void txtdiscount_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtgrandtotal.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(txtsubtotal.Text)-(Convert.ToDouble(txtdiscount.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtsubtotal.Text))).ToString("#,0.00");
}
```

After insert data into database I need to clear this textboxes.How can do this?I used textbox.text=""; for all text boxes but txtgrandtotal didn't clear (conflict with txtdiscount_TextChanged_1 event ).

Comment: Check to see if textgrandtotal.Text = "" if so skip the line of code you have in the textchanged event

Comment: Not a wise idea to call Convert.ToXXXX on an textbox where your user can type anything. What happens if you type a letter instead of a number?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all textBox text to `""` and just calculate `txtgrandtotal` when `txtsubtotal` and `txtdiscount` is not empty!

```
private void txtdiscount_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtsubtotal.Text == "" || txtdiscount.Text == "")
        return;
    txtgrandtotal.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(txtsubtotal.Text) - (Convert.ToDouble(txtdiscount.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtsubtotal.Text))).ToString("#,0.00");
}
```